# Model State Validation in ASP.NET WEBAPI Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

I am trying to use model validation in ASP.NET WEBAPI Core. Below mentioned is the code from my model.

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "1.0", "90.1")]
public decimal price{ get; set; }
```

My understanding is, if I pass any value which is not in between 1.0 - 90.1, the `ModelState.Valid` should be *false*.

Here is the url I tried to call the method,

```
http://localhost:57270/api/testprice?price=132.7492634
```

Since the value which I have passed greater than 90, I was expecting `ModelState.Valid` as *false*. But always the `ModelState.Valid` is coming as *true*.

Am I missing anything? Please help?

Comment: What about `[Range(typeof(decimal), 1.0, 90.1)]`?

Comment: @FrankNielsen : Thanks for the reply. When we use type in RangeAttribute, we have to mention both min and max value as strings only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of other users, I am posting the answer to this question.

To get full functionality of data annotations in .net core, we need to add the below line in *ConfigureServices* function in *startup.cs* file:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddDataAnnotations();
```

Hope it helps. Have a nice day to all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[Range(1.0, 90.1)]
public decimal price{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Jack, Thanks for the reply. I have tried this. Its not working. I am still getting ModelState.Valid as true.